# Eclipse plugin like Intellij's InspectionGadget?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, intellij-idea

is there a plugin for eclipse like the InspectionGadget for Intellij?

On Intellij when you write some code that can be simplify you have a warning message/dialog on the editor and you have information to how to change the code.

Just a very simple example:

```
private int foobar(){

int test = someCalculation();

return test;

}
```

i get a warning message that this code can be changed to

```
return someCalculation();
```

and other similar helps.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use IntellJ IDEA?

Comment: I just used the community edition of Intellij that is limited on some features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for as code analysis [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/eclipse.html) is pretty good.. But that should not work with following example :)

Comment: At least there is something similar.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think there is.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @Conner It is an answer. It's a yes or no question. I answered no.

Comment: This comment was automatically generated by the beta review system. The website automatically detected your post as being one of low quality. I didn't mean any offense by my review; I just think short, non-descript answers like this one are better suited as comments.

Comment: @Conner Ah, I see. No offense taken!